# Make my app available for iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I have iOS mobile app that currently works on every device with iOS 7 and higher.

It become harder and harder to maintain and support it for iOS 7 so I want my next version of app with all the glorious features to run at least at iOS 8. 
The problem is I still have users with iOS 7 devices.

What can I do to make my app available for iOS 7 users?

P.S. making separate apps doesn’t look so great

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to support iOS 7 and later or iOS 8 and later? If you choose to support iOS 8 and later your existing iOS 7 users can keep using the app they already have.

Comment: You seem confused, so if you are planning to support iOS 8 and higher from the next version of the app then your iOS 7 users can use the last version as it is but they can't update the app from next version, it's that simple.

Comment: And what about new users with iOS 7 - how would they will be able to download it ?